# iOS project structure

Tags: ios, xcode, macros

I'm developing an iOS application for several customers. The app has to share its basic functionality between the customers, but configuration parameters have to be different.

In order to do so I created multiple targets, each for every customer. The targets include their unique parameters inside target's plist file like this:
[image]

I was asked to add an additional parameter. As opposed to ones above, this parameter received from external place. Each customer provides its own SDK (framework) with different API in order to get the additional param.

My question is how to build the project, so it's possible to get this parameter from different SDKs, but still share the other parts of the code? I mean how can each target only include its unique framework & implementation, but and not to include others? Am I supposed to use preprocessor macros for that purpose?

Thanks.